# Spring Validation ... Validator is working, but errors are not displaying

Tags: spring, validation, websphere-portal

Ok I have two pages in my application that are very similar. addressForm.jsp, and termsForm.jsp .... Each page has a Spring validator for it's fields. Address form is working fine. The terms form validator runs, I see the errors in the errors object in the log, but the jsp is not displaying the errors.

Address form  ...

```
<form:form htmlEscape="false" name="addressForm" commandName="vendorTransmittal" method="post" action="${onboardingActionUrl}">
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>
```

Terms form ... only difference is the encoding type, as the terms form has a file upload piece ... not sure if that could be messing up the error display.

```
<form htmlEscape="false" name="termsForm" commandName="vendorTransmittal" method="post"  action="${uploadFileUrl}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>
```

The errors are there

[5/4/12 9:23:17:649 EDT] 0000003a SystemOut     O 52945 [WebContainer : 6] DEBUG com.bedbath.vendorportal.onboarding.validator.TermsFormValidator  - Retrieved error Field error in object 'vendorTransmittal' on field 'VTShippingMinimumTypeId': rejected value [1]; codes [invalidValue.shippingMinimumType.vendorTransmittal.VTShippingMinimumTypeId,invalidValue.shippingMinimumType.VTShippingMinimumTypeId,invalidValue.shippingMinimumType.java.lang.Integer,invalidValue.shippingMinimumType]; arguments []; default message [Shipping Minimum Type should not be entered if there is no Shipping Minimum]

Controller recognizes the errors, and routes back to the same page as expected. They just don't display .

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your second form is HTML `<form>`, not Spring `<form:form>`. `<form:errors>` can only be used inside `<form:form>`.